# HttpClient File Download Error - Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, httpclient

I've written an application that in part can download files from a specific web service.  The code utilizes an HttpClient to make the calls.  The problem is that occasionally I will get a failed request with the following exception message:

Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.

I did run across these blog posts, in which the author had to revert the protocol version to 1.0, disable keep alive, and limit the number of service point connections:

- http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-the-connection-was-closed/
- http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/

I followed those instructions, as best I knew how and still got the error.  I also made sure to keep a single instance of the HttpClient around (following the Singleton principle).

What is interesting is that when running Fiddler I've yet to get the error, which makes me think that there is something that can be done on the client side since Fiddler appears to be doing something to keep the connection alive (though the issue is so sporadic this may be a red herring).

A couple more notes:

- The error invariably occurs in the middle of a download (never when initiating the request).
- The file continues to download up to the point of failure (there are no extended pauses or delays first).

**--UPDATE--**

The error occurs on the following line:

```
responseTask.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

The following is the full exception:

```
System.AggregateException occurred   HResult=-2146233088   Message=One
or more errors occurred.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Form1.StartDownload() in c:\Projects\Visual Studio 2012\Demo\Demo\Form1.cs:line 88   InnerException:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Error while copying content to a stream.
       InnerException: System.IO.IOException
            HResult=-2146232800
            Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
                 HResult=-2147467259
                 Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
                 Source=System
                 ErrorCode=10054
                 NativeErrorCode=10054
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 InnerException:
```

**--UPDATE #2--**

I thought I would try changing the completion option from 'content read' to 'headers read'.  This also failed with the same exception, albeit in a different location (where the TODO comment is, reading the content stream).

**--UPDATE #3--**

I can confirm that the web service (which is hosted in IIS) is aborting the connections (the IIS logs show a win32 status code of 1236 - ERROR_CONNECTION_ABORTED).  To try and narrow things down, the MinFileBytesPerSec metabase property was set to zero (on the off chance the client stopped pulling down data momentarily) and the connection is still being aborted.  I've double checked all the timeouts and buffer sizes I can think of to no avail.  Clawing at thin air at the moment.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Client Setup:**

```
private void SetupClient()
{
    // In case we're taxing the web server, limit the number
    // connections we're allowed to make to one.
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1;

    // Set up the progress handler so that we can keep track of the download progress.
    _progressHandler = new ProgressMessageHandler();
    _progressHandler.HttpReceiveProgress += ProgressHandler_HttpReceiveProgress;

    // Create our HttpClient.
    _client = HttpClientFactory.Create(_progressHandler);
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
    _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
}
```

**Download Logic:**

```
private void StartDownload()
{
    // Create the request.
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/Download"))
    {
        // Revert the protocol version and turn off keep alive in accordance with:
        // http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-the-connection-was-closed/
        // http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/

        request.Version = new Version("1.0");
        request.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "false");

        // Set the cancellation token's timeout to 30 minutes.
        int timeoutInMilliseconds = 30 * 60 * 1000;

        using (CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeoutInMilliseconds))
        {
            // Making sure that the message isn't "complete" until everything is read in so we can cancel it at anytime.
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseTask = _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

            responseTask.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = responseTask.Result)
            {
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Request failed!");
                }

                Task<Stream> streamTask = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                using (Stream contentStream = streamTask.Result)
                {
                    // TODO: Save to disk.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Networks are not completely reliable things, all sorts of things can cause breakages: you do need to deal with errors and have some form of re-try logic. It would help to know where in your code you are you seeing the error.

Comment: Absolutely @Richard.  The code posted above is a fairly stripped down, vanilla version.  Trying to the get the exact location the error occurs.  When I do I will update my post.

Comment: I just ran into this same error today and came across your question. After reading your question, I decided to update the `client.Timeout` property to a longer timespan and that solved it for me. Did you ever figure out what was the issue for you?